# Salir de un ciclo si no hay Items seleccionados

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola a todos y buenas noches,

Tengo el siguiente código, con un if y foreach con el cual valido si hay Items seleccionados en un ListView si los hay entonces insertar en la base de datos con otro foreach solo los items que estén seleccionados.

El problema es que si no hay items seleccionados muestro un MessageBox al usuario indicándole que no hay Items seleccionados, pero este se muestra la cantidad de n veces que existan items en el listview, entonces como puedo evitar estas repeticiones si no hay Items seleccionados muestra el mensaje al usuario y aborta la ejecucion.

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item1 in listCapture.Items)
        {
            if (item1.Selected == true)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listCapture.CheckedItems)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO activities (activity, coordinate_x, coordinate_y, idaplication) values (@ACT_act, @ACT_coorx,@ACT_coory,@ACT_idapp)", cnx);
                        cnx.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_act", item.SubItems[1].Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_coorx", item.SubItems[2].Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_coory", item.SubItems[3].Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ACT_idapp", cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue);
                        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_coorxy", cbPurchaseOrderNo.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cnx.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Records has been saved!","Succed!!!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Items not yet selected...","Select Items!!!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que anidar ciclos para realizar esto. Puedes hacer todo con un `if`, verificando la propiedad `count` de `CheckedItems` para determinar si hay registros seleccionados o no.

Además:

- No es necesario crear muchos comandos SQL, con uno que crees es suficiente y solo le vas asignando valores a los parámetros.
- Siempre recomiendo utiliza transacciones, para que toda la operación sea un éxito o falle. Si pierdes conexión a la base de datos a mitad de la grabación, solo unos cuantos registros quedarían, lo cual generalmente no es deseable.
- Notifica al usuario solo al final, éxito o fallo. Igual si no hay registros seleccionados.
- No intentes manejar excepciones a todo nivel... es mejor dejar que las excepciones fluyan hacia otras partes de la aplicación. Generalmente, si se va a mostrar un mensaje de error, tener un solo punto donde esto se realice y no tener miles de mensajes por toda la aplicación.
- No abras y cierres conexión a la DB por cada registro, lo cual es una operación costosa, si el usuario selecciona 50 registros, basta con conectarse y desconectarse una vez de la DB.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (ListViewItem item in listCapture.CheckedItems > 0) {
        cnx.Open();
        try {
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            transaction = cnx.BeginTransaction();
            try {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO activities (activity, coordinate_x, coordinate_y, idaplication) values (@ACT_act, @ACT_coorx,@ACT_coory,@ACT_idapp)", cnx);
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACT_act", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACT_coorx", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACT_coory", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ACT_idapp", SqlDbType.Int);
  
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listCapture.CheckedItems) {
                    cmd.Parameters["@ACT_act"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["@ACT_coorx"].Value = item.SubItems[2].Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["@ACT_coory"].Value = item.SubItems[3].Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["ACT_idapp"].Value = cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            } catch {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        } finally {
            cnx.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Records has been saved!","Succed!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Items not yet selected...","Select Items!!!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, una duda si fuese un Procedimiento Almacenado tendria que declarar todo esto de la transacción dentro del mismo sp, es correcto?
@jachguate

Comment: Si fuese un procedimiento almacenado, que se ejecuta dentro del motor de base de datos, no hay manera que tuvieras acceso a un ListView, que pertenece a la interfaz del usuario, así que no comprendo bien de lo que hablas. Todo lo que se ejecuta a nivel de base de datos ya está ocurriendo en el contexto de una transacción. Son las herramientas de programación las que dan la fantasía del _auto-commit_ cuando no declaras explicitamente una transacción, haciendo _commit_ inmediatamente después de cada operación que se lanza a la DB.

Comment: Gracias comprendo, lo que comentas investigue un poco acerca de esto.
Gracias nuevamente y saludos.
DS
@jachguate

Answer (score 2):

Pero solo deberias iteras una de las dos listas

- iteras los `Items` preguntando en el `if` por el `Selected`
- iteras directamente los `CheckedItems`

pero no ambos

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(listCapture.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Items not yet selected...","Select Items!!!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }


    string query = @"INSERT INTO activities (activity, coordinate_x, coordinate_y, idaplication) 
                    values (@ACT_act, @ACT_coorx,@ACT_coory,@ACT_idapp)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
    cnx.Open();
            
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listCapture.CheckedItems)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_act", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_coorx", item.SubItems[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_coory", item.SubItems[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ACT_idapp", cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACT_coorxy", cbPurchaseOrderNo.Text);
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    
    cnx.Close();
    
    MessageBox.Show("Records has been saved!","Succed!!!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

}
```

Podrias validar si hay items antes de iterar.

Tambien debes definir el SqlCommand solo una vez y luego limpiar los parametros en cada iteracion

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro lo tomare en cuenta.
Saludos
@Leandro Tuttini